# Using a dictionary across multiple subs in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a dictionary which is defined in one sub, which I'd like to use to get Values from the keys, which are in different subs.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

ID = Me.TextBox1.Value
Dim rwd As Worksheet
Set rwd = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data")


If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(summ.Range("A:A"), Me.TextBox4.Value) > 0 Then
    Dim rowsDict As Object
    Set rowsDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim counter As Long
    counter = 1
    For i = 2 To rwd.Range("A" & Application.rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If rwd.Range("A" & i).Value = ID Then
            RowAndNumber = CStr(counter) & "-" & (rwd.Range("J" & i).Value)
            Me.ComboBox3.AddItem (RowAndNumber)
            rowsDict.Add RowAndNumber, i '
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()

    n = rowsDict.Item(Me.ComboBox3.Value)
    Me.bTextBox131.Value = rwd.Range("J" & n).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Pass the dictionary as a variable: `Private Sub SomeSub(rowsDict as Object)`. Pretty basic stuff tbh, recommend reading up on passing variables.

Comment: @Absinthe but this is the combobox change handler, so you can't pass a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the dictionary in the module scope

```
' Move your declaration to outside your Sub
Dim rowsDict As Object
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    ID = Me.TextBox1.Value
    Dim rwd As Worksheet
    Set rwd = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data")

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(summ.Range("A:A"), Me.TextBox4.Value) > 0 Then
        Set rowsDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Dim counter As Long
        counter = 1
        For i = 2 To rwd.Range("A" & Application.rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If rwd.Range("A" & i).Value = ID Then
                RowAndNumber = CStr(counter) & "-" & (rwd.Range("J" & i).Value)
                Me.ComboBox3.AddItem (RowAndNumber)
                rowsDict.Add RowAndNumber, i '
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
        Next
    ' You're also missing an End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
    n = rowsDict.Item(Me.ComboBox3.Value)
    Me.bTextBox131.Value = rwd.Range("J" & n).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: That'll work but we all know the mess globals can cause, better to pass the object imo.

Comment: @Absinthe How are you going to pass a dictionary to a `ComboBox` Event? + I've been working with VBA for 8 years now daily using Public variables when it is necessary and have never ran into an issue. Sloppy code gets you into issues.